# Firefox: control shift t shortcut does not work since upgrade to 14.04

Tags: keyboard, firefox, shortcuts

Since upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10, the Control-shift-t shortcut allowing to bring back latest deleted tabs in firefox does not work anymore.

My keyboard configuration is latin-be.

This is my version of Firefox (same in help-> about firefox):

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy firefox
  Installé : 28.0+build2-0ubuntu2
  Candidat : 28.0+build2-0ubuntu2
 Table de version :
 *** 28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This problem is not happening on another machine with the same keyboard layout.

I suspect the problem is that the upgrade failed and could not complete some tasks at the end of the upgrade. Is there some way to finish the upgrade ? Everything else seems fine and `dpkg --configure -a` returns nothing.

Comment: confirm that firefox is the latest firefox. (try to upgrade firefox) go to firefox's menu and choose about firefox should show you a button to update, and then either checking, upgrading or up to date.

Comment: It is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In the Location bar, type or paste 'about:config' press Enter.

If necessary, click I'll be careful, I promise

In the Search box, paste browser.sessionstore.max

Double-click browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo, in the prompt, type 0

Double-click browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo, in the prompt, type 0

This should reset the values of the settings

Comment: Modifying the parameters had no effect. The previous value was set to the default which is 10 for max_tabs_undo and 3 for max_windows_undo